# Adding a X-value line on nvd3

Tags: charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using a chart similar to the sample linechart example.
I want to implement an x-value line on the chart, something similar to [this flot examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html).

I tried with something like the following, but can't get it to work. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyGqN/4/). Any ideas?

```
   svg.on("mousemove",function(){
        //this is my attempt but clearly its not working
        m1 = d3.mouse(this);
        var line = svg.append("line")
                   .attr("y1",0)
                   .attr("y2",height)
                   .attr("x1", m1[0])
                   .attr("x2",m1[0]);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your jsFiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/MyGqN/5/

Let's first make a line by adding

```
 svg.append("line").attr("id","rLine");
```

After our declaring the svg variable

then change your code to be

```
svg.on("mousemove",function(){
    m1 = d3.mouse(this);
    svg.selectAll("#rLine")
               .attr("y1",0)
               .attr("y2",height)
               .attr("x1", m1[0])
               .attr("x2",m1[0])
                .attr("stroke","red")
                .attr("stroke-width",2);

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if theres an easy way to set the y locations to the top/bottom of the chart (and not the svg)?

Comment: Since you have the SVG size static you can set "y1",30  and "y2",height-50  . If you found the answer helpful could you give it an accept?

Comment: How to dynamically get the height of the chart itself?